# R Shiny Matrix Multiplication

Tags: r, matrix

I am currently developing an Monte Carlo Simulation with R's shiny.
Unfortunately, I am stuck at some and can't see the error right now. I tested the code for the simulation before and it works. What I am trying now is to get it into a Shiny app.

This is part of my server.r code. It is only a part of the complete code, but I think I narrowed the error down to this part. When I run the app and hit an action button which trigger the `dataScenario()`function, I get the following error:

> Error in beta %*% t(dataScenario()[[1]]) :    verlangt
>   numerische/komplexe Matrix/Vektor-Argumente

Sorry for the German, not complete sure about the proper translation, but basically R complains that the matrix multiplication can't be performed since one of the elements is not a vector/matrix.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({

z <- rep(seq(10, 1000, 10), 4)
x <- c(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 100), rep(3, 100), rep(4, 100))
t.container <- data.frame(time = rep(NA, length(z)),
                          up = rep(NA, length(z)),
                          low = rep(NA, length(z)),
                          geo = z,
                          strength = x
)

# Censoring
v <- runif(n = nsim, min = 0, max = 1)
X <- as.matrix(dataScenario()[[1]])
Z <- as.matrix(dataScenario()[[2]])

for(i in 1:length(z)){

  mu.beta.rebel <- gamma.0 + gamma.geography * z[i] + gamma.geography.q * z[i]^2 + gamma %*% t(Z)

  mu <- mean(beta.0) + mu.beta.rebel * x[i] + beta %*% t(X)

  t <- (- log(v) / (exp(mu)))^(1 / alpha)

  t <- apply(t, 1, mean)

  t.container[i, 1] <- mean(t)
  t.container[i, 2] <- stats::quantile(t, probs = c(0.025))
  t.container[i, 3] <- stats::quantile(t, probs = c(0.975))

}
})
```

The `dataScenario()` looks like this

```
  dataScenario <- eventReactive(input$simButton, {

# Recode support
rebel.support <- 0
gov.support <- 0

if(length(input$support) == 2){
  rebel.support <- 1
  gov.support <- 1
} 

if(length(input$support) == 1){
      rebel.support <- ifelse(input$support == 1, 1, 0)
      gov.support <- ifelse(input$support == 2, 1, 0)
}

# Recode
peace <- ifelse(input$peace == TRUE, 1, 0)

# Define covariates on macro level (X)
X <- cbind(rep(input$polity, nsim),
               rep((input$gdp - 3556), nsim),
           rep(((input$pop * 1e06) - 1.174e+08), nsim),
               rep(input$ethnic, nsim),
           rep(input$type, nsim), # Conflict Type (no coup d'eta)
               rep(rebel.support, nsim), # Rebel Support (no rebel support)
               rep(gov.support, nsim), # Government Support (no government support)
               rep(peace, nsim), # Termination Type (no peace settlement)
               rep(input$n.rebels, nsim) # N rebels (1 rebel group)
)

# Define covariates on micro level (Z)
Z <- cbind(rep(rebel.support, nsim), # Rebel Support (no rebel support)
           rep(input$n.diamonds, nsim),
               rep(input$oil, nsim)
)

scenario.list <- list(X, Z) 

return(scenario.list)
```

})

In order to check the class and dimensions of the elements with should be multiplied, I also added this:

```
  output$test1 <- renderText({
    paste("X is of class: ", class(dataScenario()[[1]]), "with ", dim(dataScenario()[[1]])[1], dim(dataScenario()[[1]])[2])
  })

  output$test2 <- renderText({
    paste("beta is of class: ", class(beta), "with ", dim(beta)[1], dim(beta)[2])
  })
```

And it outputs when running the App:

> X is of class: matrix with 100 9 
>   beta is of class: matrix with 1500 9

I know that it is redundant to save the two scenarios in X and Y as matrix, since both are already matrixes. Also tried it using directly `dataScenario()[[1]]` which gives the same error as above.

Helpful comments are very welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: beta is loaded in the beginning of the app, sorry I actually did not know that stack overflow is the right place, is there a way to move it over there?

Comment: Yes, I will flag this question as "off topic" and request that it be moved. You're free to do the same.

Comment: Could your code be modifying `beta` somewhere else? Can you try printing the dimensions of `beta` again (using `print`) right before you compute `beta %*% t(X)` to see if it still has the correct dims? On a side note, you can pull `beta %*% t(X)` out of the for loop since it's independent of `i` (more efficient than recomputing it every time).

Comment: Added `print(dim(beta))` and `print(dim(X))` right before the matrix multiplication. Also changed X to have 1500 rows (should not matter at all..). Still getting: Error in beta %*% t(X) : 
  verlangt numerische/komplexe Matrix/Vektor-Argumente

Comment: Any other ideas were the error might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Shiny returned at least on element from `input` as an character. Hence, the dimensions were correct, but the whole data inside the matrix was `char`... Solved it by adding the following line:

`X <- matrix(data = unlist(lapply(X, as.numeric)), nrow = nsim, ncol = 9)`